# How do I know if $u(t)$ and $y(t)$ is linear to each other?

Tags: control-theory, parameter-estimation, optimal-control, linear-control, system-identification

Assume that we have input $u (t) $ and output $y (t) $ from transfer function $G (s) $. How do I know if input $u (t) $ and output $y (t) $ is linear to each other if the model $G (s) $ is unknown?

Comment: Is there any chance you could get some more input/output pairs? If so, you could check if $f(au_1(t)) + bu_2(t)) = af(u_1(t)) + bf(u_2(t))$. Not a proof, but an indication.

Comment: @MaxHerrmann assume that the data can be curvefitted on an arbitary function.

Comment: But are there arbitrarily many input/output pairs, or just one?

Comment: @MaxHerrmann I don't know. I have a theory. Estimate $G(s)$ from data, then simulate the model with $u(t)$ and compare it with $y(t)$. But that seems to be very time consuming. Bust be a better way? Like a proof or something.

Comment: If output is generated from a transfer function, the system is already linear even if you don't know what it is. Otherwise, please provide more details. Also, saying two functions are linear to each other doesn't make any sense, you can only talk about the linearity of the system.

Comment: If you don't know nothing about the relation between $u$ and $y$, what about taking a couple of samples at discrete points in time $((g(t) * u(t))_{t = t_i},y_i)$, and evaluating some linear correlation measure on it? This resembles the approach suggested by you, but for a sampled data set, and over a finite time horizon. You could also limit your investigation to the classes of input functions your system is usually opposed to.